# application process stops unexpectedly

Tags: android

I m new to android so i don't know how to interpret this logcat i searched this site but not found any solution to what i m facing.a little help will be appriciated.thank you in advance. 
Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>               
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.splashscreen"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8
     />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.splashscreen.StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.splashscreen.STARTINGPOINT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.splashscreen.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
Log cat :
    02-21 17:24:21.026: W/dalvikvm(447): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560) 
02-21 17:24:21.026: E/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10 02-21          17:24:21.026: E/AndroidRuntime(447): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.splashscreen.MENU }    02-21 17:24:21.026:E/AndroidRuntime(447): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
02-21 17:24:21.026: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
02-21 17:24:21.026: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
02-21 17:24:21.026: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
02-21 17:24:21.026: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.splashscreen.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:31)
```

Splash.java

```
 package com.splashscreen;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 public class Splash extends Activity {
 MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    ourSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.splashscreen.MENU");

                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };

    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` and the code that causes this exception.

Comment: at com.splashscreen.Splash$1.run(Splas h.java:31) Line 31 has an error

Comment: post your Splash activity code.

Comment: line no 31 is startActivity(openStartingPoint); and i have checked there is no error in that

Answer (score 0):

Change in `Splash.java`

```
     Intent("com.splashscreen.MENU");
```

Change to

```
     Intent("com.splashscreen.Menu");
```

Comment: Ok you must change Intent("com.splashscreen.MENU");

Comment: It must work .may you have another problem after this problem.the logCat shows another thing or same above posted.?

Comment: logcat is same as before.

Comment: Do you have `Menu.java`in your src_splashscreen folder?

Comment: yeah i have Splash.java,StartingPoint.java and menu.java in my src folder

Comment: So change `menu.java` to `Menu.java`All Activity must be in src> com > splashscreen

Answer (score 0):

Create a Activity Menu as the class name in com.splashscreen package folder
for example

```
public class Menu extends Activity{ }
```

Then call the below code in the timer code finally block

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(StartingPoint.this,com.splashscreen.Menu.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: i wanted to do this using Class class's method forName and secondly if i use StartingPoint.this this will be of no mean in class menu as "startingPoint.this" will not point to Menu class

Comment: see this doc to start a activity http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html